# convert the value in 1st column into row names

Tags: r

I'd like to the convert the values in the first column into row names.

There are some similar questions about it like this
[Convert the values in a column into row names in an existing data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555408/convert-the-values-in-a-column-into-row-names-in-an-existing-data-frame-in-r)

However, the thing is that I would like to do that in the files with listed up.
What should I do to apply into multiple files (ex. `int_file[[i]]`)?

```
> exp = list.files(pattern=glob2rx("*_input_*.txt"))
> int_file = lapply(exp, read.table, sep="\t", header = T)

# I tried with int_files=lapply(exp, red.table. sep="\t", row.names=NULL)

> exp
[1] "1_input_1.txt" "2_input_2.txt"
> dim(int_file[[1])
[1] 2000 20
> dim(int_file[[2]])
[1] 3000 20

> type(int_file[[1]][1,1])
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this in a single operation rather than with a loop?  Not everything in `R` must be done without a loop. :)

Comment: `row.names=1` perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I have bunch of files to do run with same code and get the result. Most codes should be ran through a loop like this. <br> for ( i in 1:length(int_file){do stuff.. int_file[[i]]}

Comment: So then just follow the solution on the page you linked, but put it inside a loop.  `for (f in exp) { df=read.table(f, sep="\t", header=T); rownames(df) = df[,someColumn]; ... }`