# Row name to be set of number

Tags: r

I want to change the row names from abcde to 12345
For example I would like to convert:

```
     Var.1 Var.2 Var.3
 A     1     5     0
 B     2     4     1
 C     3     3     2
 D     4     2     3
 E     5     1     4
```

into

```
       names Var.1 Var.2 Var.3
  1     A     1     5     0
  2     B     2     4     1
  3     C     3     3     2
  4     D     4     2     3
  5     E     5     1     4
```

The example is from another question, but I ask reversely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert the values in a column into row names in an existing data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555408/convert-the-values-in-a-column-into-row-names-in-an-existing-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Yes we are similar but reverse the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the "rownames" command:

```
rownames(mydataframe)<-c(1:5)
```

To add the current rownames as a new column to the dataframe:

```
cbind(names = rownames(mydataframe), mydataframe, row.names = NULL)
```

This edit includes the suggestion to make the function call generic.

Comment: Or better for all size data frames: `rownames(mydataframe)<-c(1:nrow(mydataframe))`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried but the column "names" is deleted. I would like to keep "names" as well

Comment: See my edits above.  I included Enrique's suggestion.

Comment: Exactly what I want to know! THANKS!

Comment: Note my edit.  Because `cbind.data.frame()` calls `data.frame()`, you can use `row.names = NULL` to remove the old row names in the same call. Also, `rownames(df) <- NULL` will always reset row names to a numeric sequence.