# Heatmap error with : 'x' must be a numeric matrix

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap

I know this question might be duplicated, but I was trying some of the solutions posted in this forum with no success, and that's why I am posting it here.

Let's start with my dataset to make it reproducible.

```
dataset <- structure(list(Comparison = c("SH vs SAP", "SH vs NEA", "SH vs ERE", 
"SH vs ERH", "SH vs NAL", "SAP vs NEA", "SAP vs ERE", "SAP vs ERH", 
"SAP vs NAL", "NEA vs ERE", "NEA vs ERH", "NEA vs NAL", "ERE vs ERH", 
"ERE vs NAL", "ERH vs NAL"), DC1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA), DC2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 
1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA), DC3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), DC4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1), DC5 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1), DC6 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), DC7 = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), DC8 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), DC9 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), DC10 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Comparison", "DC1", "DC2", "DC3", 
"DC4", "DC5", "DC6", "DC7", "DC8", "DC9", "DC10"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
15L))
```

I have tried to change the dataset to a matrix, as this been suggested in other posts. However, it keeps giving the same error

```
heatmap(dataset)
heatmap(as.matrix(dataset))

Error in heatmap(dataset) : 
  'x' must be a numeric matrix

Error in heatmap(as.matrix(dataset)) : 
  'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

I tried to convert to numeric the columns, but the error keeps. And so is the case when I remove `DC1` and `DC2` columns which contain `NA` values.

Any help to spot the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`dataset[, 1]` is character so `as.matrix(dataset)` is a **character** matrix. This explains:

> 'x' must be a **numeric** matrix

Your probably want

```
heatmap(as.matrix(dataset[, -1]))
```

[image]

> And how can I include the names of the rows on the right?

Set the `Comparison` variable as the `rownames` of the matrix:

```
m <- as.matrix(dataset[, -1])
rownames(m) <- dataset$Comparison
heatmap(m)
```

[image]

So your real issue is really [Convert the values in a column into row names in an existing data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5555408/4891738) although the problem is presented with `heatmap`.