# Use the values in an data frame in R for colnames et rownames

Tags: r, shiny-reactivity

I am new to shinyR and I would like to convert the values in a column of an existing data frame into row names and the values in a column into col names  .  Something like this  data:

```
   Date             Type  Count 
  23 May 2005        A     2
  24 May 2005        B     1 
  25 May 2005        D     3  
  26 May 2005        D     3   
  26 May 2005        A     3
```

Into this :

```
   23 May 2005   24 May 2005  25 May 2005   26 May 2005 
 A        2          0             0             3
 B        0          1             1             0
 Other    0          0             3             3
```

I tried :

```
vcol <- length(data$date)
table119 <- matrix(data$count, ncol=vcol,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(table119) <- data$type
colnames(table119) <- data$date
table_stathas <- - DT::renderDataTable({table119()})
```

but it is not working

It is different from [Convert the values in a column into row names in an existing data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555408/convert-the-values-in-a-column-into-row-names-in-an-existing-data-frame-in-r) , I want to change the colnames and the rownames with the value of the columns Date and Type that are not uniques

Comment: @KoenV not really,I the value of the column Type are not distinct and so is the the value from the column Date that I want to make as colnames

Comment: Understood. I will remove the `flag`.

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option would be

```
df$Type[!df$Type %in% c("A", "B")] <- "Other"
xtabs(Count ~ Type + Date, df)
```