# Linear regression using same variable twice

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a multivariate linear regression on a data set but the summary has one of my categorical variables appearing twice with different coefficient values.

Below is a snapshot of the dataset and the regression output.

''' data = read.csv("Data.csv")
data1 = select(data, Generosity, MALE, ECON, FIRST, FIELD, EXP, ECON300, ECON400, EMPLOY, STUDLOAN, DEBT)
head(data1)

reg1 = lm(Generosity~MALE + ECON + FIRST + FIELD + EXP + ECON300 + ECON400 + EMPLOY + STUDLOAN + DEBT, data = data1)
summary(reg1)'''
[image: dataset preview][image]

FIELDSOCSCI appears twice?

Comment: code, including packages and versions?

Comment: I would check the variable FIELD with `unique(dat$FIELD)` to see if there are two SOCSCI entries. Maybe one has an extra space at the end...

Comment: [Please provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555408/convert-the-values-in-a-column-into-row-names-in-an-existing-data-frame-in-r) data and code as plain text, not images, so users can easily copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your dataframe if there is a second spelling of SOCSCI and if so, decide for one and change the other by replacing it in your code.
Acutally, `lm(formula, data,...)` should not result in two entries for the same variable.